# Matching sequence of numbers with pattern in excel 2013

Tags: regex, excel, excel-formula

I have a sequence of number from `1 000 000` to `9 999 999` `(Total: 9,000,000)`. I've generated them in the excel and I would like to match them in following formats

Last 6 digits in:

```
 1. XXX XXX (For example, 000 000 or 111 111 or 222 222)
 2. X00 000 (For example, 100 000 or 200 000 or 300 000)
 3. XYY YYY (For example, 122 222 or 233 333 or 411 111)
 4. XY0 000 (For example, 230 000 or 750 000 or 120 000)
 5. XYZ ZZZ (For example, 231 111 or 232 222 or 233 333)
 6. X00 Y00 (For example, 200 300 or 100 400 or 500 600)
 7. XXX Y00 (For example, 333 300 or 666 600 or 777 700)
 8. XXX YYY (For example, 111 333 or 222 555 or 555 666)
 9. XX YY ZZ (For example, 11 22 33 or 22 33 44 or 44 55 66)
 10. X0 Y0 Z0 (For example, 10 20 30 or 30 40 50 or 60 70 80)
```

Would it be possible to do with regex or vba in excel 2013?

Since I don't have knowledge in Excel, should I seek someone's help for a simple program for such matching?

Comment: @pnuts Yes. For instance, for each million blocks, I would want to match with the 10 patterns and return the matched ones (I've just updated the pattern list). For 3# (and the rest), yes it could also be 460 000 and 780 000. The hierarchy would be 1st digit of the million blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VBA, but I believe you will need to set up each classification separately, and also ensure that they are in an order so as to not overlap.

Here is a partial example, showing a few VBA techniques, which you should be able to extend. I only dealt with the rightmost 6 digits and initially constructed a string; and also put each digit into an array element to make the testing formulas simpler.

```
Option Explicit
Function Classify(N As Long) As String
  Dim I As Long
  Dim S(1 To 6) As String
  Dim sN As String
sN = Format(Right(N, 6), "000000")
For I = 1 To 6
    S(I) = Mid(sN, I, 1)
Next I

If Left(sN, 3) = Right(sN, 3) Then
    Classify = "XXX XXX"
ElseIf S(1) <> 0 And Mid(sN, 2) = 0 Then
    Classify = "X00 000"
ElseIf S(1) <> 0 And Mid(sN, 2) Like WorksheetFunction.Rept(S(2), 5) Then
    Classify = "XYY YYY"
ElseIf S(1) <> 0 And S(2) <> 0 And S(1) <> S(2) And Mid(sN, 3) = 0 Then
    Classify = "XY0 000"
elseif ...


End If


End Function
```